# Adding data via person picker but, UITableView do not reload

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I've created an UITableView with cells and i am trying to add a person's phone and name information into a cell via some functions. The problem is when i try to add a person's info, it is being added into my data array but, i cannot see the new info on UITableView cell. I tried to use `reloadData` function to reload UITableView, it was no use.

I have arrays for people's numbers and names. Also, i have a button which adds a person via **ABPeoplePickerNavigationController**.
addedContacts.h :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@import AddressBook;
@import AddressBookUI;

@interface addedContacts : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate, ABPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate, UITableViewDelegate,
UITableViewDataSource>{
    NSMutableArray* people;
    NSMutableArray* numbers;
    IBOutlet UITableView *tableview;
}
- (IBAction)addPerson:(id)sender;

@end
```

I use **commitEditingStyle** function to delete a person's information from the tableview. In addition, I keep people's information in defaults of application.

addedContacts.m :

```
#import "addedContacts.h"

@implementation addedContacts

-(void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];

}

- (IBAction)addPerson:(id)sender {
    ABPeoplePickerNavigationController* picker = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
    picker.peoplePickerDelegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker didSelectPerson:(ABRecordRef)person property:(ABPropertyID)property identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifier {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}

-(BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person{

    NSUserDefaults* defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    numbers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[defaults objectForKey:@"numbers"]];
    people =  [[NSMutableArray alloc]  initWithArray:[defaults objectForKey:@"people"]];

    if(numbers.count == 0 && numbers.count == 0){
        numbers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        people =  [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    }

    NSString *contactName = CFBridgingRelease(ABRecordCopyCompositeName(person));
    NSString* nameField = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", contactName ? contactName : @"No Name"];
    ABMultiValueRef phoneRecord = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
    CFStringRef phoneNumber = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phoneRecord, 0);
    NSString* phoneField = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)phoneNumber;
    CFRelease(phoneRecord);

    [people addObject:nameField];
    [numbers addObject:phoneField];

    [defaults setObject:people forKey:@"people"];;
    [defaults setObject:numbers forKey:@"numbers"];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    return NO;
}

-(void)peoplePickerNavigationControllerDidCancel:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Remove the row from data model
    [people removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [numbers removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    // Request table view to reload
    [tableView reloadData];

}


-(NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInTableView: (UITableView*) tableView{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView*) tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    NSUserDefaults* defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    numbers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[defaults objectForKey:@"numbers"]];
    return [numbers count];
}

-(UITableViewCell*) tableView: (UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    NSUserDefaults* defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    numbers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[defaults objectForKey:@"numbers"]];
    people = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[defaults objectForKey:@"people"]];
    NSLog(@"%@",numbers);
    NSLog(@"%@",people);
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

    if(cell == nil){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailButton;
    }

    NSLog(@"%ld", (long)indexPath.row);
    NSLog(@"%ld", (long)people.count);

    NSString* Tname = [people objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString* Tnumber = [numbers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = Tname;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = Tnumber;

    return cell;
}

@end
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: is `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` getting called?

Answer (score 1):

1) this is something strange:

```
if(numbers.count == 0 && numbers.count == 0){
    numbers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    people =  [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

}
```

i think you mean

```
if(numbers.count == 0 && people.count == 0)
```

2) i think you mast insert reload of table after you add your new object into people and numbers arrays

```
[people addObject:nameField];
[numbers addObject:phoneField]; 
[tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: Yes, that if block has to be like you stated but, the problem still is current. Even though i added reload data after adding new object to people and numbers, it did not change the result.

Comment: are you sure than when you try to add a person's info, it is being added into your data array? You need initialize an empty array using:  [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

Answer (score 0):

My hunch is that, there this a bug in the `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection` code. You need to return count of `people` or `numbers`. Not get the value from the user defaults. Since they don't have the newly added person and number.

```
-(NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView*) tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [numbers count];
}
```